# In Shapeless, can I supply an instance of `LabelledGeneric` for non case classes that will enable automatic derivation of typeclass instances?

Tags: scala, code-generation, typeclass, shapeless

I have a json library that defines a **notion of** `ReadCodec` (which defines how to read json) by following the typeclass pattern in Scala. This library uses **Shapeless**' `Typeclass` construct to **derive automatic instances of** `ReadCodec` for any case class for free.

Now, I have a code generator that **generates classes in Scala that are not case classes** (but probably should be). I could have the code generator generate instances of ReadCodec for each class which is what we have right now. But now if I want the generated classes to support some new form of serialization, I need to modify code generation to output instances for this new typeclass.

Is there a way I can **modify the code generator to output classes with instances of** `LabelledGeneric` or something else that would tap into the mechanism that generates (via macro) automatic instances for case classes? This way, the generated code can interop with any typeclass pattern that uses Shapeless' `Typeclass` for materialization of instances.

Comment: Sure, just generate the `LabelledGeneric` instances. What's the difficulty / question?

Comment: @Imm Haha, funny, I just assumed it could not be that simple... Still expect to run into issues but I guess I will just have to try it to find out. Thx for giving me some confidence that this might actually work.

Comment: @lmm It's a reasonable question—defining the `LabelledGeneric` instance isn't trivial (thanks to the fact that you need to refer to singleton types, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's one tricky step, but you definitely can define your own `LabelledGeneric` instances. For the sake of example here I'll use Alex Archambault's [argonaut-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless) library, which doesn't literally use `TypeClass`, but it does use `LabelledGeneric`, and the principle is the same.

First for our class:

```
class Foo(val i: Int, val s: String)
```

Then for our instance:

```
import shapeless._, labelled._, record._, syntax.singleton._

implicit object fooGeneric extends LabelledGeneric[Foo] {
  val iw = Witness('i)
  val sw = Witness('s)

  type Repr = FieldType[iw.T, Int] :: FieldType[sw.T, String] :: HNil

  def from(r: Repr): Foo = new Foo(r('i), r('s))
  def to(t: Foo): Repr = ('i ->> t.i) :: ('s ->> t.s) :: HNil
}
```

Note that we need a way to refer to the singleton types for the record keys in `Repr`, so we define a couple of witnesses first. That's the tricky part.

Now you just write this:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._, Shapeless._
```

And then:

```
scala> implicitly[EncodeJson[Foo]].encode(new Foo(42, "foo"))
res0: argonaut.Json = {"s":"foo","i":42}
```

I could put together a `LabelledTypeClass` example if you'd like, but the idea is exactly the same.

Comment: Note that `Witness` instances are now dispensable, as `Witness` now has a type selector: ``type Repr = FieldType[Witness.`'i`.T, Int] :: FieldType[Witness.`'s`.T, String] :: HNil``

Comment: @al3xar Yeah, I guess I should have mentioned that syntax. It's still a little too magical for my taste.

Comment: This is so awesome thx! I just now found the time to try it out and after a little tinkering it worked!